# The folder name is invalid on selecting SFTP path in Azure data factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, linked-service

I am trying to create a dataset for a SFTP linked to service in the azure data factory pipeline. After selecting the path I am getting the error "The folder name is invalid".
Here is the Image
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I created storage account with sftp preview enabled and I created local user to sftp with container named sftp.
Image for reference:
[image]

I uploaded a csv file into that container.
Image for reference:

[image]

I created a sftp linked service in data factory by filling required details.
Image for reference:

[image]

I created sftp dataset using above linked service and uploaded file successfully.
To upload a file, I click on browse option in file path and my container is opened. In my container I am having input directory.
Image for reference:

[image]

I click on input directory, and I selected my file.
Image for reference:

[image]

My file is uploaded successfully.
Image for reference:

[image]

dataset is created successfully in data flow.
data preview of dataset:

[image]

Once check your directory if the folder is there or not.